# Since set-cookie has been deprecated is there a way to STILL make it work (compatibility?)

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

On an existing web site we have many page using

```
<meta http-equiv="set-cookie" content="cookiename=value; expires=Fri, 22-Sep-17 08:57:01 GMT; path=/">
```

Set-cookie has been deprecated in chrome (see below), is there a way to keep compatibility (without change in code) ? At least temporally until correcting every place it's in use... 
[image]

Comment: voting down without explanation is not very positive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is no way to avoid deprecation.

The best on the EXISTING site is to change the meta by a script tag (goal is to minimize change):

```
REM {update expires date:1 month};
AdjDate := @Adjust(@Now;0;1;0;0;0;0);
Months:="Jan":"Feb":"Mar":"Apr":"May":"Jun":"Jul":"Aug":"Sep":"Oct":"Nov":"Dec";
Days:="Sunday":"Monday":"Tuesday":"Wednesday":"Thursday":"Friday":"Saturday";
Time := @Right("0"+@Text(@Hour(AdjDate));2) + ":" + @Right("0"+@Text(@Minute(AdjDate));2) + ":" + @Right("0"+@Text(@Second(AdjDate));2);
ExpDate := Days[@Weekday(AdjDate)] + ", " + @Right("0"+@Text(@Day(AdjDate));2) + "-" + Months[@Month(AdjDate)]  + "-" + @Text(@Year(AdjDate)) + " " + Time + " GMT";

"<script type=\"text/javascript\" id=\"set-cookieJS\">document.cookie = \"" + cookiename + "=" + CartID + "; expires=" + ExpDate + "; path=/\";</script>";
```

The existing site is in Domino using Formula.